# Want to use grep in for loop to grep lines with [43], special chars [ & ]

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am trying out the following command:

```
for i in `cat list_to_216 `; do egrep ResalathTable\[$i\] Res_149 ; done
```

the file, list_to_216 contains the following data:

```
adv@oam # head list_to_216
715
716
717
```

and the file `Res_149` contains:

```
ResalathTable[715].field1=RIZZ
ResalathTable[715].field2=1
ResalathTable[715].field3=681
```

I cant seem to get the right output I need...

Comment: Are you grepping for `ResalathTable` or `annoIdTable`? Current input file wouldn' t match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgrep` should be help you in getting the job done :-)

```
for i in `cat list_to_216 `
do
    fgrep ResalathTable[$i] Res_149
done
```

Comment: Looks like this is the simplest way to go about. Thank you.

Comment: This is not simplest but buggy, everything is subject to shell expansion. There is absolutely no need of `cat` here.

Comment: Ok, so whats the best suggestion ? should i be using the while option ? Ok, i will try that now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -f if your pattern resides in a file like below:

```
grep -f list_to_216 Res_149
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while read -r ; do
    grep "ResalathTable\[$REPLY\]" Res_149
done < list_to_216
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is simplest here, but this `awk` should do to:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++;next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' list_to_216 Res_149
```